# Return mark_safe string from __str__

Tags: python, django

I have a class that takes a complex data type and returns the string representation of it using the `__str__` method.  Then, I can use the object directly in a template.  However, I also want to return HTML in the string as well.  If I wrap the string in `mark_safe` and display it in the template, the HTML is escaped.

Here is the class:

```
class StrTest:
  def __init__(self, num):
    self.num = num

  def __str__(self):
    return mark_safe("<span style='color:red'>Number is " + str(self.num) + '</span>')
```

Here's how I pass it to a template:

```
  return render(request, 'my_template.html', {
    'str_test': str_test,
    })
```

and my template:

```
{{str_test}}
```

If I do `{{str_test|safe}}`, the HTML is no longer escaped.

Is it possible to return a `SafeString` from `__str__` without having to call `safe` from the template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't; the return value from `__str__` **must** be a `str` value.

Template languages that support the `__html__` attribute however will automatically call that instead:

```
class StrTest:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)

    def __html__(self):
        return mark_safe(
            '<span style="color: red">Number is {0}</span>'.format(self.num))
```

Django supports this as of version 1.7, see [ticket #7261](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7261).

Comment: It seems like [has this?](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7261)  I tried the above, but `__html__` was not called, but I'm using 1.6.  It seems like it was added in 1.7.